# Mac SMB connections to Windows 2003 server, leaving Open Files

Tags: windows-server-2003, mac-osx

We have several Mac clients (Both 10.5, and 10.6) mounting a share from a Windows 2003 server.  At least once a day, our archivist will go into this share to archive items from it, to the backup server.  Most of the time, she has no issues:  she copies the folder to the archive server, when it's done, she deletes it from this share.

Then, she will come upon one, and it will say she doesn't have permission.  When I go into the Open sessions, it will say that a particular user has a READ lock on the file, in Windows 2003.  Of course, this person does not have the file open, and the only way we can delete it, is to close the open session on the file.

My thoughts:

- The Mac likes to "sprinkle" Hidden "Resource Forks" on SMB servers, and possibly, when this Mac who last wrote to that share, closes out of the file, and these files still exist.
- Windows 2003 has a bug, that doesn't properly "release" the OPLOCK on the file?
- Steve Ballmer just doesn't like Mac's, so he wants to annoy everyone by not releasing file locks :-)

What can be done about this?  It happens every day, and sometimes several times per day!

Many thanks,

Bruce

Comment: Nobody?  Someone must have something on this...

Comment: We have had better success by disabling "named streams".  Here's how to do that:  http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4017?viewlocale=en_US

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have the right idea.  Seems like stopping OS X from sprinkling resource forks is the way to go.

Also when you look to see which user has the file open do you check on their local machine to see if there's a process with that file open.  My suspicion is a bug is a particular program.